# multiple scanner inputs on same line

Tags: input

I have an array that requires input for each place.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[]=new int[9];
    System.out.print("Enter nine Numbers: ");
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
      array[i]=scanner.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Let's use for this example the inputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Output:

```
Enter nine Numbers: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Desired Output:

```
Enter nine Numbers: 123456789
```

Comment: All you have to do is just give space while giving inputs. i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanner.next()` then separate your input values using a space.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  array[i] = scanner.next();
}
```